# special characters not being displayed correctly in utf-8 encoded file

Tags: php, html, utf-8, metadata, special-characters

I have a strange situation.
I am specifying utf-8 in the meta data of my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
         ....
   </head>
   <body>
        <? include("extras.php"); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

but my speacial characters "ä, ö, å" are being display incorrectly.

Even more strange through is that the same characters used int the included file (hard coded no loaded from php), are being displayed correctly?

can anyone enlighten me as to why this might be?

Comment: What is the actual encoding of the extras.php file? What does “incorrectly” mean in “"ä, ö, å" are being display[ed] incorrectly”?

Answer (score 0):

Encode the special characters, for example, the letter `ä` you should encode as `&#228;`
You can use an HTML encoder/decoder (there are many available online):
http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/encode.aspx

or do it [*programmatically*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: Yes, I could encode every special character, but normally this is not required when utf-8 is specified in the meta data, and using encoding is not very practical for editing/human readability of html. What I can't figure out is why seting utf-8 in the metadata is not working.

Comment: The examples you provided are not UTF-8 - it's cyrillic (ISO8859-5)

Comment: I just changed<meta charset="utf-8" /> to <meta http equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and now all of the special characters are being displayed correctly?

Comment: @Finglish your last comment - are you asking or saying ? if the latter - on which browsers did you test it ?

Comment: @Finglish, you must have changed something else (which caused the real change), since the two `meta` tags are equivalent.

Comment: @alfasin The change made it work correctly in chrome, firefox, ie8, ie9.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela This really confused me too, as I also am sure these shoud be equivalent. I only changed it in desperation, but the fact is one works and the other doesn't. No idea why :(

Comment: @Finglish, can you provide testable cases (self-contained code samples and/or URLs) that differ only in the use of the two different `meta` tags and cause different results?